# How to scroll page to the element with Jquery ScrollTo() using class selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

On a base of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element) question i'd like to ask a question: How can solve the same problem using class selector `$('.class')`?

I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

When trying to run this

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('input.ng-invalid').offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Comment: have you wrapped the code in DOM ready event??

Comment: You have an error elsewhere in your code

Comment: No but i run it from console when the page is loaded

Comment: The question is how to make it work using class selector :)

Comment: Unless `input.ng-invalid` doesn't return an element, then calling `offset` would return `undefined`, and `top` wouldn't be defined, but that should give you a different error.

Comment: @adeneo it does return an element, but offset is still undefined

Comment: But the error you've posted seems completely unrelated. What you've got should work just fine, see this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/w8fp9qke/1/**

Comment: @adeneo Oh sh*t you are right, the problem is that i have no jquery, I worked with built in Angular's jqlite... :) Totaly forgot it....

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var sc = $('div[class="classname"]').offset().top;
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: (sc - 30)
        },
        'slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but this is what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/65q6xo95/1/

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.ng-invalid:first').offset().top
}, 2000);
```